# Setter with upper bound of Interface, but getter without wildcard

Tags: java, generics

As recommended by Sonar rule [RSPEC-1452](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1452),

> Generic wildcard types should not be used in return types

How can I define setter method of a property that accepts a `List<? extends Item>`, but getter method that returns `List<Item>`?

Consider the below contract of `Cart` interface:

```
interface Cart {
    public List<Item> getItems();
}

interface Item {
    public int getCost();
}
```

Clients of this contract do not need to know about any known implementations of `Cart` or `Item` interfaces, e.g.

```
void getValue(Cart cart) {
    int sum = cart.getItems().stream().mapToInt(Item::getCost).sum();
}
```

However, the library that implements the `Cart` interface obviously has to deal with concrete classes. Assume it (or its `Builder`) also has to expose a `setItems` method so that another internal class can set the entire list of items. Upper bound of Interface allows to pass a `List<DefaultItem>` to `setItems` method.

```
static class DefaultCart implements Cart {

    private List<Item> items;

    public void setItems(List<? extends Item> items) {
        this.items = new ArrayList<Item>(items);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

I am not happy with the above `setItems` method as it creates another copy of the list. What is a better way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I define setter method of a property that accepts a `List<? extends Item>`, but getter method that returns `List<Item>`?

You can't, because `List<? extends Item>` is not a subclass of `List<Item>`, i.e. they are not assignment compatible with each other.

For explanation, see: [Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/5221149)

What you can do, is to make your class generic, so you don't use wildcard:

```java
static class DefaultCart<E extends Item> implements Cart {

    private List<E> items;

    public void setItems(List<E> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives a compile error: `The return type is incompatible with Cart.getItems()`

Comment: @Somu Then you either need to make `Cart` generic too, or you need to do what you're doing in the question code, since, as already explained in this answer, `List<Dog>` is not assignment-compatible with `List<Animal>`, so you can't otherwise call `setItems()` with a `List<Dog>` and expect `getItems()` to return a `List<Animal>`.